# Updates do not appear on GitHub pages on my React project

Tags: reactjs, github, github-pages

I have a bug on my React project. The updates do not appear on GitHub pages. I tried:

1. Delete cache data.
2. Redeploy (only index.js name changes, but nothing changed in GitHub pages).
3. Make some edits to index.html.
4. Make a custom domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try and start from scratch, following "**[Deploying a React App* to GitHub Pages](https://github.com/gitname/react-gh-pages)**": once that is working, you can re-import your current work in that new project.

The other approach is to use [GitHub Action](https://dev.to/dyarleniber/setting-up-a-ci-cd-workflow-on-github-actions-for-a-react-app-with-github-pages-and-codecov-4hnp): again, you can try and follow that tutorial.

Comment: @Habibamohammad Great, can you detail in a comment what you did to make it work?